# Selenium c# custom expected conditions for innerText

Tags: c#, selenium

**the html**

> `<span id="banner">Rolling in 10.00...</span>`

**my code**

```
public void waitroller()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("waiting roller");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(PropertiesCollection.driver, TimeSpan.FromDays(2));
        wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
        {
            IWebElement element = PropertiesCollection.driver.FindElement(By.Id("banner"));
            if (element.Text == "Rolling in 20.00...")
            {
                return element;
            }

            return null;
        });

    }
```

**OR**

```
public void waitroller()
    {

        new WebDriverWait(PropertiesCollection.driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(By.Id("banner") , "Rolling in 20.00..."));
    }
```

I'm stuck with this innertext because the innertext in the html is always changing and i want to make a webdriverwait that waits until the innertext in the span banner is "Rolling in 20.00" . Is there any way to make custom expected conditions because I am not understand custom expected condition.

what i need is something like this

new WebDriverWait(PropertiesCollection.driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(PropertiesCollection.driver.FindElement(By.Id("banner"), "Rolling in 20.00...");

but this is not work because i think the id="banner" is innerText

there is one way that work but can't work for long because i think it is the wrong way of doing it . i loop the element banner many times and check if the innerText is equals to "Rolling in 20.00..." but have error also

Answer (score 1):

```
public void waitroller()
{

    Console.WriteLine("waiting roller");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(PropertiesCollection.driver, TimeSpan.FromDays(2));
    IWebElement bannerElement = PropertiesCollection.driver.FindElement(By.Id("banner"));
    wait.Until((d) =>{ return bannerElement.Text.Contains("Rolling in 20.00"); });

}
```

Comment: I hope this should help you.

Comment: i am not understand you my friend i return void

Comment: Oops! i missed that. I assumed that you waitroller will return the element. Sorry in that case you can skip If condition part and instead of ' wait.Until((d) =>{ return bannerElement.Text.Contains("Rolling in 20.00"); });' just use wait.Until((d) =>{ return bannerElement.Text.Contains("Rolling in 20.00"); });' try if it is working...

Comment: wait.Until((d) =>{ return bannerElement.Text.Contains("Rolling in 20.00"); }); will wait for 2 days(the span you set). If the Text turns to "Rolling in 20.00" within that 2 days ,code continue to next line, else will return timeout error

Comment: i am sorry my friend it doesn't work it cannot register the "rolling in 20.00"
and i need to check "rolling in 20.00"

Comment: my iwebdriver is in another class PropertiesCollection.driver is that fine ?

Comment: Hmm... Please share the solution once you are able to do it. :)

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem as far as i know

Comment: can you explain in detail what does your code does ?> maybe i can figure it out i not understand this part   wait.Until((d) =>{

Comment: The wait .Until will check for the condition to be true. And waits till the time out. We had a scenario where a value displays after certain period of time. During that time it displays as loading, later actually text will display, I have used the same code. First will find the control,  next will apply wait for my actual text to display and it worked. So I thought it would help you as well

Comment: Can you please let me now what error or trouble you faced when you tried the code that i gave you. Im very positive with my code as it worked for me... I see that you have a different question raised for the same it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "innertext", but with Selenium's WebDriverWait you can wait for whatever you want. You don't have to use the ExpectedConditions, they're only for programmers' comfort.

Example:

```
new WebDriverWait(...).Until(driver => driver.FindElement(...).Text.Equals(...));
```

On the other hand, your problem might be a completely different one. Is your "roller" a countdown where the text changes very fast? In this case you might never reach the expected condition. I think Selenium checks the expected conditions every 500 milliseconds, so it doesn't even notice when "Rolling in 20.00" is displayed for just let's say 50 millisecods and then has already changed to "Rolling in 19.95" when Selenium checks for the next time.

Comment: new WebDriverWait(PropertiesCollection.driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.5)).Until(PropertiesCollection.driver => rolling.Text.Equals("Rolling in 20.00...");

Comment: Then maybe you should check for numeric value equal **or less than** 20.00! Otherwise it's a matter of luck whether you ever reach the expected condition or not.

Comment: my friend that is not a value it's an innertext "Rolling in 20.00..." > "Rolling in 19.59..." > "Rolling in 19.58..."

Comment: Yes, my friend, but you can remove the "Rolling in " and the "...", convert the remaining string to a double value and compare it with 20.0, can't you?